# I cannot duplicate anything correctly in Pose-Mode

Tags: pose-mode

I am a beginner and I'm using Blender 2.79 and I have a problem with duplicating a character of mine, it isn't an obj so if there's any way I can make it one? Or just tell me how to duplicate them properly

[image]

Comment: I am a beginner and I'm using Blender 2.79 and I have a problem with duplicating a character of mine, it isn't an obj so if there's any way I can make it one? Or just tell me how to duplicate them properly

Comment: Are you using any drivers?

Comment: Sorry what's that?

Comment: How is the mouth rigged?

Comment: You can just check the model by downloading it here http://www.mediafire.com/file/kfb689a6idaqs32/RobloxRig_V4.zip/file

Comment: You probably didn't duplicate everything. There are several hidden boolean object (with driven shapekeys), which are hidden. You have to unhide all of them, then duplicate all of them. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnP56.png).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a *[9. Support Request](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/30849)* using a model from another author. An option would be (1) to contact the original author of the rig and ask him how to use it and/or (2) to study the rig carefully and provide all information in the question. You can always [edit] your question to provide additional information.